# How to align table row to the right with css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to move a table row containing navigation links for my website from being left aligned to being right aligned, but no matter what I edit nothing moves.  I've only recently started learning HTML and CSS so any help would be appreciated.

#### HTML

```
    <div id="nav">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="Images/Home.png"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="Learn.html">
                    <img src="Images/Learn.png"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="Practice.html">
                    <img src="Images/Practice.png"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="About.html">
                    <img src="Images/About.png"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #47B531;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav tr {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav td {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: would you like the whole table to be aligned right or just  the contents of the table rows?

Comment: `no matter what I edit nothing moves` - What did you edit?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
<table align="right">
```

instead of just table tag.

Comment: Thank you, but I just switched out tables for <nav>.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the navigation menues are designed using lists instead of tables. Here a very very simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Home.png"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html"><img src="Images/About.png"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html"><img src="Images/Contact.png"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="Donate.html">Donate</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li{
    float:right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The options using this method is endless, give it a try and let us know if you got stuck or have questions about it.
Heres the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Vh3/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the links on the right, within the `div` element, without changing the table cell rendering from the current one, just add the rule

```
#nav table { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Dave's suggestion next time. Lists are much more efficient and easier. But to answer your question you can use `align=right` on the table to fix it.

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uhLuh/

Answer (score 0):

Awareness of current web standards is crucial. I recommend diving head into HTML 5 & CSS3.
I believe that you should be looking to follow HTML 5 standards with CSS3.

Here is how to ideally approach a HTML5 navigation element and the base CSS3 elements and attributes that should get you pointed in the right direction :)

```
HTML5
<nav>
 <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Home.png"/></a> 
 <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Home.png"/></a>
 <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Home.png"/></a>
 <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Home.png"/></a>
</nav>

CSS3
ul { }

nav ul 
{float: right;      *Adjust to suit
 text-align:right;  *Adjust to suit
 list-style: none;} *Adjust to suit

nav ul li { }
nav ul a { }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you.  I actually did what you have outlined here before I checked here.

Comment: If I have text instead of images, how do I adjust the text to be inline with the images?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... text instead of images? then how would they be inline with the images?

Comment: Like for navigation links, using a png instead of text.  And having the text that would remain be at the level that is at the center of said png.

Comment: is it possible that you add the text to the png?